# Using the report execution web service, how can I tell if a report's table returned no rows?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a C# project which consumes the ReportExecution2005.asmx web service. In my project, I loop through some database records, pass the row's data to the report's parameters, then render the report.

The report is a simple, one dataset, one table report, that I end up exporting to Excel.

When I'm rendering the report, I don't know if the parameters I am passing will actually result in the report's dataset/table returning any rows. If the report does return data, then I send my report out in an email. However, if the the report's table is empty, then I need to skip this report and move on the next report.

Is there anyway I can check my rendered report to see if the dataset or table returned any data?

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds more like something that could be done in the backend sql than in the report.  The report just generates, to my knowledge there is nothing baked in that can do this.  The knowledge of a subscription is pretty basic .... but you can do dynamic subscription that can go off of database logic.

I believe you could do a multi tiered approach to make a subscription be dynamic for this.

1. Create a job in SQL Database for a database that keeps track of reports having data.  Just do a simple insert into RecordTable select (reportname), dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0), Count(*) from (tabledataset).
2. Have this job run every day at a set time to populate if your dataset has rows or not.
3. Create a dynamic subscription to perform a query if the rowcount is greater than zero to send out, if not do not.

Comment: Ya, I figured the execution service didn't have anything out of the box for my problem. I as you are suggesting, I just need to tackle it from another angle. Other ideas I have, is to read the exported XLS file, or export it as XML first, and parse that for existing data.

Comment: Yes exactly.  The Database set up will take you longer but in the end will be a more sound solution.  Generally with .NET and databases they are more work but once in place it is easier to manipulate data in the long run.